# Division of a grouped sum in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

When querying a prometheus metric, I would like to group the sum and divide the grouped results on a second metric.

While the simple grouped sum function works:

```
sum by(somefield) (gauge_metric)
```

This query with the division included returns "no data":

```
sum by(somefield) (gauge_metric) / sum(second_metric{deployment="a-value"})
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Beeing novice in prometheus I had missed the `ignoring` and `group_left` functions, this solved it:

```
sum by(somefield) (gauge_metric) / ignoring(somefield) group_left sum(second_metric{deployment="a-value"} )
```